# Match word before and after colon

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:
"FIELDS--> FIELD1:  \r\n FILED2: \r\nSOURCEFIELDS--> KEY1: VALUE1, KEY2: VALUE2, KEY3: VALUE3\r\"

I want would want the following from the above string:

```
[FIELD1, ]
[FIELD2, ]
[KEY1, VALUE1]
[KEY2, VALUE2]
[KEY3, VALUE3]
```

So I still want the value if its empty. It will be empty sometimes and other times it won't. Also the amount of fields may vary.

I have tried:

```
x= 'FIELDS--> FIELD1:  \r\n FILED2: \r\nSOURCEFIELDS--> KEY1: VALUE1, KEY2: VALUE2, KEY3: VALUE3\r\n'
   x.split(':')
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Almost perfectly works.  How do I handle it if the value has dots, and dashes?

Comment: Thanks! If you post the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'(\w+) *:(?: *([\w.-]+))?', x)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3ecPPw/1).

**Details**

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `*:` - 0 or more spaces and a `:`
- `(?: *([\w.-]+))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `*` - 0 or more spaces
  - `([\w.-]+)` - Group 2: one or more word, `.` or `-` chars.

Comment: Explanation is very helpful. I wish could upvote twice.