# Match Phrase before and after colon

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
'FIELDS--> FIELD1: Random Sentence  \r\n FIELD2: \r\nSOURCEHINT--> FIELD3: 
 value.nested.value, FIELD4: 5.5.5.5, FIELD5: Longer Sentence, with more words-and punctation\r\n'
```

I want the following from the string above:

```
[FIELD1, Random Sentence]
[FIELD2, ]
[FIELD3, value.nested.value]
[FIELD4, 5.5.5.5]
[FIELD5, Longer Sentence, with more words-and punctation]
```

I still want the value if it is empty and I want the full sentences. The amount of fields may vary as well.
This is similar to [Match word before and after colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086690/match-word-before-and-after-colon), but in this case I want the full sentence instead of just the word. Additionally the FIELD names can change. So they could KEY3, instead of FIELD1.

I tried:

```
re.findall(r'(\w+) *:(?:(.*)?), x)
```

It stops matching after the first match, so this just outputs FIELD1, and matches everything after it.

Comment: Try something like `(\w+) *: *(.*?)(?=\s*(?:FIELD|$))`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gKITkT/1).

Comment: What if the key isn't named FIELD, but something else?

Comment: Then what is the right-hand boundary for a field value? What chars can a valu consist of?  If you cannot formulate that rule, you cannot use a regex.

Comment: Right hand boundary would be a word followed by a colon

Comment: Then, `(\w+) *: *(.*?)(?=\s*(?:\w+:|$))`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/gKITkT/2)

Comment: Yup, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you may use

```
r'(\w+) *: *(.*?)(?=\s*(?:\w+:|$))'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gKITkT/3)

**Details**

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `*: *` - a `:` enclosed with spaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any chars, 0 or more repetitions, as few as possible, up to the first occurrence of
- `(?=\s*(?:\w+:|$))` - 0+ whitespaces followed with either 1+ word chars followed with `:` or an end of the string position.